# centralize data annotation for MVVM

Tags: c#, data-annotations

Is there any better way to centralize data annotations for models and view models, or even different view models but they have some properties are the same.?

One way I came out with is to use specialize data annotation. like [AgeRange], with built in range from 0 to 100.

```
public class Model{
[range(0,100)]
public int Age{get;set;}
}

public class ViewModel{
[range(0,100)]
public int Age{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: You could put a `Model` instance into your view model.

Comment: Ye, but I have a situation that not all properties in the model relates to some view models.